# Embedding 'Zxing embedded' in Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, qr-code, zxing

I need use a custom layout or a fragment in [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library.

I try to write a fragment, but the app only show me a black square with the text "..scan code..". Not show me the cam.
I need make to see the camera in the bottom half of the screen, for put buttons in top.

The codes is a copy of the library samples.

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
            Button scan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_from_fragment);
            scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scanFromFragment();
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        public void scanFromFragment() {
            IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();
        }
```

**FragmentLayout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="example.zxing.MainActivity" //change this for my activity
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"> 

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scan_from_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/scan_from_fragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

With this fragment, when I clcik the button, show in other activity the camera in full screen.

I read that it's posible put into a SurfaceView or TextureView, but i don't know how make that.

Comment: I am sorry your question is not clear,  are you trying to merge camera preview in your fragment screen ? that is all I got from line "show in other activity the camera in full screen."

Comment: excuse my english ;) I need read barcodes with zxing, but not in fullscreen camera. Use my own layout (or fragment), for show the camera only in the middle bottom screen.